# Win10 programData files with hex filenames?

Tags: windows, file

I'm running Windows 10, and note that my programData folder contains dozens of files with hexadecimal file and folder names. Anyone know what they, and if they are safe to delete? See for example, the folders surrounded with curly brackets, and filenames starting: ea4ae7af-xxxx-x

```
Directory of C:\ProgramData

13 Aug 2016  12:01  <DIR>  {039b9585-712c-1}
24 Oct 2016  23:42  <DIR>  {052F5A09-B284-EDA2-BFE1-B9E000248071}
20 Aug 2016  14:14  <DIR>  {09017ad4-512c-0}
06 Aug 2016  19:54  <DIR>  {0989b384-112c-0}
25 Nov 2016  21:49  <DIR>  {0ca76cfe-312c-1}
06 Aug 2016  14:15  <DIR>  {11af99ff-212c-1}
27 Nov 2016  20:39  <DIR>  {15D107F3-A27A-B058-1651-2436E7122443}
25 Nov 2016  21:49  <DIR>  {16cb7ce6-412c-0}
12 Oct 2016  18:14  <DIR>  {184B900B-AFE0-27A0-D1E9-E58DE58F188A}
13 Aug 2016  12:01  <DIR>  {1b25513b-712c-0}
30 Sep 2016  19:35  <DIR>  {1bf7731f-112c-0}
25 Nov 2016  21:49  <DIR>  {23780c81-212c-1}
20 Aug 2016  14:14  <DIR>  {26799d2c-512c-0}
30 Sep 2016  23:26  <DIR>  {359a98f9-312c-0}
25 Nov 2016  21:49  <DIR>  {36ef270a-712c-1}
25 Nov 2016  21:49  <DIR>  {4f852513-712c-0}
25 Nov 2016  21:49  <DIR>  {54f05bc9-412c-0}
23 Oct 2016  23:37  <DIR>  {55901e0d-112c-0}
23 Oct 2016  23:37  <DIR>  {7cc1682f-112c-0}
29 Jul 2016  07:40  <DIR>  176ae28e-1295-1
29 Jul 2016  07:40  <DIR>  176ae28e-3635-0
30 Nov 2016  18:42  <DIR>  3b085a5f
21 Jan 2016  13:23  <DIR>  Adobe
30 Nov 2016  13:54  47,070 agent.1480514086.bdinstall.bin
21 Jan 2016  14:30  <DIR>  ASUS
30 Nov 2016  14:00  <DIR>  BDLogging
30 Nov 2016  14:07  <DIR>  Bitdefender
30 Nov 2016  13:54  <DIR>  Bitdefender Agent
30 Nov 2016  14:00   377,662 cl.1480514321.bdinstall.bin
16 Jul 2016  11:47  <DIR>  Comms
30 Nov 2016  18:40  <DIR>  Comodo
05 Aug 2016  16:43  <DIR>  Corel
21 Jan 2016  18:11  <DIR>  CorelDRAW Graphics Suite X5
03 Jul 2016  22:49  <DIR>  CorelDRAW Graphics Suite X8.1
14 Aug 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-00d1-0
29 Jun 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-0113-0
13 Aug 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-0517-0
08 Aug 2016  10:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-0613-0
23 Oct 2016  23:42  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-07a5-1
23 Jul 2016  12:11  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-0847-1
22 Aug 2016  10:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-09c3-1
03 Oct 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-0a01-1
23 Jul 2016  23:59  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-0c61-0
09 Aug 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-0df3-1
23 Aug 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-1361-0
06 Aug 2016  18:15  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-1433-1
27 Jun 2016  11:06  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-1587-0
24 Jul 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-18b5-1
23 Jul 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-19c5-1
28 Jun 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-1a67-1
09 Aug 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-1b57-0
26 Oct 2016  07:53  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-1cd7-0
23 Aug 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-1d23-1
22 Aug 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-1ec7-1
03 Oct 2016  10:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-21d1-0
22 Aug 2016  10:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-22c7-0
22 Aug 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-22f1-1
24 Aug 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-23c1-1
21 Aug 2016  04:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-2431-0
08 Aug 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-24e3-0
29 Jun 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-25d1-0
06 Aug 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-25e5-0
30 Sep 2016  23:25  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-2653-1
21 Aug 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-2657-0
25 Oct 2016  08:42  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-26e5-0
04 Oct 2016  07:00  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-2783-1
06 Aug 2016  18:15  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-2815-0
23 Jul 2016  12:11  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-2821-0
24 Jul 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-2935-1
09 Aug 2016  10:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-2a33-0
24 Aug 2016  04:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-2c23-0
09 Aug 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-2c27-0
22 Aug 2016  04:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-2c67-1
24 Jul 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-2cf3-0
23 Oct 2016  23:37  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-2ee1-0
27 Jun 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-3023-1
21 Aug 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-3085-1
13 Aug 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-3175-0
23 Aug 2016  10:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-3353-0
22 Aug 2016  04:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-3365-0
13 Aug 2016  12:01  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-33b1-1
24 Jul 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-3483-0
20 Aug 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-3531-1
21 Aug 2016  10:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-3677-0
23 Oct 2016  23:37  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-3785-1
24 Aug 2016  10:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-3895-0
21 Aug 2016  04:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-39a1-1
07 Aug 2016  23:32  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-3b67-1
22 Aug 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-3de5-0
07 Aug 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-40e3-1
03 Oct 2016  10:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-4123-1
07 Aug 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-4131-1
04 Oct 2016  07:00  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-4263-0
25 Oct 2016  23:42  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-42c3-0
26 Oct 2016  07:53  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-42d1-1
24 Aug 2016  04:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-4473-1
23 Oct 2016  23:42  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-46e5-0
24 Aug 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-4757-0
25 Oct 2016  08:42  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-47e1-1
29 Jun 2016  10:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-4b83-1
23 Aug 2016  04:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-4bc5-0
23 Oct 2016  23:37  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-4e53-0
14 Aug 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-4f17-1
08 Aug 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-4f31-1
24 Oct 2016  23:42  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-4f87-0
21 Aug 2016  10:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-5075-1
24 Oct 2016  08:06  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-5153-1
06 Aug 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-5167-1
04 Oct 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-51c7-1
07 Aug 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-52a3-0
24 Aug 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-5681-0
08 Aug 2016  10:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-56b3-1
09 Aug 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-5727-1
28 Jun 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-58c1-0
27 Jun 2016  11:06  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-5ab7-0
28 Jun 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-5ac7-0
24 Oct 2016  08:06  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-5ae3-0
27 Jun 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-5e15-1
23 Aug 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-6121-1
30 Sep 2016  19:34  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-6131-0
14 Aug 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-6261-0
27 Jun 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-6401-0
03 Oct 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-6437-0
28 Jun 2016  10:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-6507-1
22 Aug 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-6521-0
23 Aug 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-6675-0
13 Aug 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-6697-1
27 Jun 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-66b1-0
09 Aug 2016  10:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-67c5-1
28 Jun 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-6821-1
21 Aug 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-6855-0
14 Aug 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-6867-1
24 Oct 2016  23:42  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-68f1-1
28 Jun 2016  10:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-69a5-0
24 Aug 2016  10:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-6ae5-1
24 Jul 2016  10:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-6b47-1
03 Oct 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-6be5-1
03 Oct 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-6c83-0
20 Aug 2016  15:42  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-6dd5-0
24 Jul 2016  10:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-6e21-0
13 Aug 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-6e67-1
21 Aug 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-6e85-1
29 Jun 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-6f37-1
23 Aug 2016  10:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-6fd7-1
25 Oct 2016  23:42  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-70f7-1
04 Oct 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-7227-0
23 Aug 2016  04:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-72e5-1
29 Jun 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-73c3-1
25 Nov 2016  21:49  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-76a5-0
29 Jun 2016  13:39  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-7743-0
13 Aug 2016  12:01  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-7855-0
20 Aug 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-7897-0
07 Aug 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-78f5-0
08 Aug 2016  23:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-7a27-1
08 Aug 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-7a75-0
07 Aug 2016  10:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-7d55-0
24 Aug 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-7d71-1
20 Aug 2016  16:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-7e41-0
20 Aug 2016  22:46  <DIR>  ea4ae7af-7fc1-1
13 Apr 2016  16:13  <DIR>  Emailchemy
01 Dec 2016  21:36     0 files.txt
30 Nov 2016  18:42  <DIR>  FLEXnet
24 Jan 2016  18:32  <DIR>  Garmin
30 Nov 2016  18:42  <DIR>  Google
17 May 2016  17:37  <DIR>  Hewlett-Packard
16 May 2016  22:03  <DIR>  HP
16 May 2016  22:03  <DIR>  HP Photo Creations
16 May 2016  22:03  <DIR>  HP Product Assistant
16 May 2016  22:08   6,293 hpzinstall.log
13 May 2016  21:26  <DIR>  InstallShield
19 Jan 2016  11:12  <DIR>  Intel
16 May 2016  16:57  <DIR>  Macrovision
21 Jan 2016  19:04  <DIR>  Microsoft Help
24 Sep 2016  17:04  <DIR>  Microsoft OneDrive
20 Jan 2016  18:24  <DIR>  Nalpeiron
27 Jan 2016  11:37  <DIR>  Nero
16 May 2016  16:57  <DIR>  Nuance
01 Dec 2016  16:39  <DIR>  NVIDIA
30 Nov 2016  18:41  <DIR>  NVIDIA Corporation
20 Jan 2016  18:24  <DIR>  onOne Software
23 Oct 2016  21:03  <DIR>  Oracle
05 Nov 2016  01:11  <DIR>  Package Cache
21 Jan 2016  17:48  <DIR>  Protexis
11 Aug 2016  21:19  <DIR>  Protexis64
17 Nov 2016  23:54  <DIR>  regid.1991-06.com.microsoft
20 Jan 2016  20:45  <DIR>  RootsMagic
20 Jan 2016  20:45  <DIR>  RootsMagic Shared
26 Jan 2016  17:07  <DIR>  Samsung
16 May 2016  16:57  <DIR>  ScanSoft
12 Oct 2016  19:50  <DIR>  Shared Space
16 Nov 2016  00:30  <DIR>  Skype
16 Jul 2016  11:47  <DIR>  SoftwareDistribution
27 Jan 2016  21:33  <DIR>  Sony
30 Nov 2016  13:57  <DIR>  Spybot - Search & Destroy
01 Dec 2016  16:39  <DIR>  TEMP
16 Mar 2016  18:58  <DIR>  UniqueId
24 Sep 2016  17:03  <DIR>  USOPrivate
24 Sep 2016  17:03  <DIR>  USOShared
01 Dec 2016  16:39  <DIR>  VMware
16 Mar 2016  19:30  <DIR>  VsTelemetry
01 Feb 2016  12:59  <DIR>  WEBREG
20 Jan 2016  20:49  <DIR>  Wrensoft
16 May 2016  16:57  <DIR>  zeon
     4 File(s)    431,025 bytes
   199 Dir(s)  105,623,052,288 bytes free
```

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that DNSUnlocker was the culprit, but I have no idea what program installed it. Although Hitman Pro was not as effective as I hoped, the following two programs were excellent, identifying and quarantining much malware:

```
[Malwarebytes AdwCleaner][1] (free)
Malwarebytes (free version) It's shame the premium version is so expensive.
```